# Finding the greatest integer not exceeding $\sum_{x=1}^{1000}\sqrt[3]{\frac {1}{x^2}}$, without calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, contest-math

The problem:

> Find the greatest integer not exceeding 
>   $$\sum_{x=1}^{1000}\sqrt[3]{\frac {1}{x^2}}$$

My attempt: so this problem is trivial with integration, but I want to do this without integration.

So this expression can be simplified as $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac {x}{x^3}}$. I know that usually, in these types of problems, the idea is to look for an easier sum that's just a little bigger, and just a little smaller, so that one can adequately guess the value of the greatest integer not exceeding it. But, it's not obvious what those 2 sums could be to me.

Answer (score 1):

$$S_n=\sum_{x=1}^n \sqrt[3]{\frac 1 {x^2}}=H_n^{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$$ where appears generalized harmonic numbers.

Using asymptotics, we have
$$S_n=3 n^{1/3}+\zeta \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+
   \frac{1}{2n^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{18n^{5/3}}
   +O\left(\frac{1}{n^{5/3}}\right)$$ So, for $n=1000$, this truncated expansion gives
$$S_{1000}=\zeta \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\frac{54008999}{1800000}\approx   27.55741870821079$$ while the "exact" value is
$27.55741870821083$

Answer (score 1):

You could use telescoping series.
Disclaimer: This is essentially the integration approach, just not explicitly.

**Claim:** Prove that  $3 x^ \frac{1}{3} - 3(x-1)^ \frac{1}{3}    >   x^ {-\frac{2}{3}} >    3 (x+1)^ \frac{1}{3} - 3 x^ \frac{1}{3}$ for $ x \geq 1$.

**Corollary:** Summing this up from $ x = 2$ to $ x = 1000$, we get the telescoping series:

$$ 3 \times 1000^\frac{1}{3} - 3 \times 1 ^ \frac{1}{3} > \sum_{x=2}^{1000}  x ^{- \frac{2}{3}} > 3 \times  1001^\frac{5}{3} - 3 \times  2 ^ \frac{1}{3}.$$

We thus have $ 27 > \sum_{x=2}^{1000}  x ^{- \frac{2}{3}}  > 26$ (can be bounded directly).

Now, adding the first term $1^{-\frac{2}{3}} = 1$, we can conclude that the GIF is 27.

---

Notes

- You can prove the claim by: multiplying throughout by $ x ^ \frac{2}{3}$, shifting terms, then cubing to get rid of cube roots.
- We started with $ x = 2$ because the $ x = 1 $ term had the most uncertainty. If the bound wasn't tight enough, then use a higher starting value.
- The claim is essentially what the integration approach does, by bounding on the left and right values.
- Could we have guessed this telescoping series without knowing integration? It could come with a lot of practice/familiarity around this type of contest problem (which one might argue is then better spent learning calculus).
- The mid-point value estimate gives a very close bound: $3(x+0.5)^\frac{1}{3} - 3(x-0.5)^\frac{1}{3} \approx x ^ {-\frac{2}{3}}$. In particular, $ 3\times (1000.5)^\frac{1}{3} - 3 \times (1.5) ^ \frac{1}{3} + 1 = 27.571$ (using a calculator), which is very close (esp considering the amount of work we did) to Claude's calculated exact value of 27.557.